# How can I specify cron timezone in k8s cron job?

Tags: kubernetes, cron, digital-ocean, cron-task, k8s-cronjobber

According to documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) I can create cron job in k8s with specify timezone like: `"CRON_TZ=UTC 0 23 * * *"`

My deployment file is:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scheduler
spec:
  schedule: "CRON_TZ=UTC 0 23 * * *"
...
```

During the deploy I am getting an error:

> The CronJob "scheduler" is invalid: spec.schedule: Invalid value: "CRON_TZ=UTC 0 23 * * *": Expected exactly 5 fields, found 6: CRON_TZ=UTC 0 23 * * *

Cron is working without perfectly timezone (`schedule: "0 23 * * *"`)

Cluster version is: `Kubernetes 1.21.2-do.2` - digitalocean.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 12):

The `CRON_TZ=<timezone>` prefix won't be available yet, not until 1.22. The inclusion in the 1.21 release docs was an error.

Originally, the change adding the syntax was [included for 1.22](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/29455/files), but it appears someone got confused and [moved the documentation over to 1.21](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/29492/files).
Supporting the `CRON_TZ=<timezone>` syntax is accidental, purely because the [package used to handle the scheduling](https://github.com/robfig/cron) was [recently upgraded to version 3](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/4b36a5cbe95d9e305d67cfda2ffa87bb3a0ccd47), which added support for the syntax. The package is the key component that makes the syntax possible and is only part of 1.22.

As of [November 2021](https://github.com/kubernetes/website/commit/b5e83e89448bcb69c095b7a056aa3f5fa4dcd4ed) the wording in the documentation has been adjusted to state that `CRON_TZ` is not officially supported:

> **Caution**:
>
> The v1 CronJob API does not officially support setting timezone as explained above.
>
> Setting variables such as `CRON_TZ` or `TZ` is not officially supported by the Kubernetes project. `CRON_TZ` or `TZ` is an implementation detail of the internal library being used for parsing and calculating the next Job creation time. Any usage of it is not recommended in a production cluster.

If you can upgrade to 1.24, you can instead use the new [`CronJobTimeZone` feature gate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#time-zones) to enable the new, official, time-zone support added with [KEP 3140](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/blob/2853299b8e330f12584624326fee186b56d4614c/keps/sig-apps/3140-TimeZone-support-in-CronJob/README.md). Note that this is still an alpha-level feature; hopefully it will reach beta in 1.25. If all goes well, the feature should reach maturity in release 1.27.

With the feature-gate enabled, you can add a `timeZone` field to your CronJob `spec`:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: scheduler
spec:
  schedule: "0 23 * * *"
  timeZone: "Etc/UTC"
```

Comment: [The docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#time-zones) now state that it's unspecified for anything before 1.24, which will introduce a feature gate (at alpha feature state) to enable timezone support in the `CronJob` spec.

Comment: @mgalgs: interesting! further up the documentation they do still mention `CRON_TZ` but in the sense that it is not officially supported, as it is an implementation detail of a library used.

Comment: @martijn-pieters: as of 1.27, `.spec.timeZone` is available as you indicated in your answer