Unable to create scheduled Tasks in SCDF - 2.11.0
I am using SCDF version 2.11.0 . Earlier I am able to create schedule tasks with CRON_TZ and it was working fine .
Recently , not able to create schedule with CRON_TZ . We are getting the below error , while creating schedule task in SCDF UI :
*Caught exception while handling a request: Failed to create schedule CronJob.batch "test-scheduler" is invalid value: "CRON_TZ=America/New_York 30 2 * * ": cannot user TZ or CRON_TZ in schedule, use timeZone field instead
Kubernetes version used : 1.29.2 ,
SCDF version : 2.11.0 ,
CRON Expression : CRON_TZ=America/New_York 30 2 * * *
As per Kubernetes version 1.29.2 , TZ and CRON_TZ field won't work and we have to user timeZone . Even with that change also we are getting below error:
**Caught exception while handling a request: Failed to create schedule CronJob.batch "test-scheduler" is invalid value: "timeZone=America/New_York 30 2 * * ": expected exactly 5 fields , found 6:[timeZone=America/New_York 30 2 * * ]
We have to schedule in SCDF UI only . I am not much clear how to use the CRON expression with timeZone field .
Thanks in advance for your help.

Your CRON_TZ field seems to be wrong, corrrect value is probably CRON_TZ='America/New_York'

Hi @JAsgarov , Thanks for the reply . I tried with CRON_TZ='America/New_York , still getting the same exception

sorry didn't look close enough, u can't use CRON_TZ and have to use (as per error message) timeZone field - see an example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68950893/how-can-i-specify-cron-timezone-in-k8s-cron-job

Hi @JAsgarov , I have tried the above solution already and got below exception:
Caught exception while handling a request: Failed to create schedule CronJob.batch "test-scheduler" is invalid value: "timeZone=America/New_York 30 2 * * *": expected exactly 5 fields , found 6:[timeZone=America/New_York 30 2 * * *] .
I don't want to schedule using deployment file . I have to schedule through Spring cloud Dataflow UI

CRON_TZ as part of the schedule property is not part of the k8s specification.
It seems that k8s now supports a timeZone field as part of the spec.
SCDF doesn't support that yet.
